# MariaDB - cannot set max_connections and wait_timeout through my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am struggling to set max_connections and wait_timeout parameters in /etc/my.cnf but MariaDB does not seem to read the parameters from the file (it reads some of the others, I haven't checked all).

My /etc/my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
#skip-grant-tables
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# network
connect_timeout = 61
wait_timeout = 86400
max_connections = 100000
max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_connect_errors = 1000

# limits
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
table_cache = 512

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

[client]
port = 3306
socket= /data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But when I check max_connections and wait_timeout variables in MariaDB, it shows the default value:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 214   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, other parameters in my.cnf are correct:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 67108864 |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_connect_errors';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| max_connect_errors | 1000  |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'connect_timeout';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| connect_timeout | 61    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can set max_connections variable from mysql command line but it resets itself when I restart the service:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set global max_connections := 10000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 10000 |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hower, for wait_timeout this does not work:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set global wait_timeout = 86400;                                                                            Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'wait_timeout';                                                                         +---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

wait timeout is set as a session variable:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name='wait_timeout' UNION SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables WHERE variable_name='wait_timeout';
+---------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+---------------+----------------+
| WAIT_TIMEOUT  | 86400          |
| WAIT_TIMEOUT  | 28800          |
+---------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Checked all my.cnf files, none of the is overriding the parameters:

```
[/] # locate my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf.d
/etc/my.cnf~
/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf
/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-clients.cnf
/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
/root/.my.cnf
```

OS: RHEL 7

MariaDB version: mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64

Comment: For checking use `show GLOBAL variables like 'max_connections';` to be sure you do not get some session specific modified values. Is that the entire `my.cnf` file? Does it maybe contain an [include directive](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.1/debian/additions/my.cnf#L189)?

Comment: show GLOBAL variables like 'max_connections'; shows the same default value of 214. That is the entire my.cnf file, no include directive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wait_timeout` is a screwball one:

"On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to mysql_real_connect()). See also interactive_timeout. "

`max_connections` claims to have an upper bound of 100000, but I would say that even 10000 is unreasonably large.  Does it work to put `max_connections=1000` in `my.cnf`?

You understand that you need to, after changing my.cnf,

1. restart mysqld
2. disconnect and reconnect to see the change
3. use `SHOW GLOBAL`, not `SHOW`, which defaults to `SHOW SESSION`.

The interaction between `GLOBAL` and `SESSION` (for both `VARIABLES` and `STATUS`) varies with the setting.  For *many, not all* things, session is *initialized* to global when you login.  And `wait_timeout` is probably the quirkiest.

**Warning**

If you had 100000 connections each running complex `SELECTs` needing, say, 3 tmp tables, then you might need 100000 * 3 * 256M = 76.8TB of *RAM* to handle the tmp table!  ( 256M = min(tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size) ).  This is a strong reason *not* to set all those things so high.

Comment: Hey Rick, yes, you were right. It does not even accept 1000 but when I tried with the value of 500, it took it. When it comes to wait_timeout, yes, the session variable is set to 2880 while global variable is set to 86400.

Comment: There are `interactive_wait_timeout` and `batch_wait_timeout`. @IokanaanIokan